# Surface Area of Cap below, Top Part of Sphere

Tags: geometry, area, spherical-geometry

How do I find the Surface Area of an oval cap below (Top of sphere)?

[image]

[Oval Cape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATliD.png)

Internet is stating: `2πRh`

However, a simple 8 radius circle is `π * 8^2 = 201`

So with 8 radius with height of 1: `2π * 8 * 1 = 50.24` (This is less than above, and doesn't make sense)

Not sure, what the real answer is.

Comment: Search the internet for this very very very well covered problem.

Comment: yeah, I gave issue above after research @DavidG.Stork

Comment: Wow... you really didn't look very well.  Here in seven seconds:  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCap.html

Comment: hi @DavidG.Stork I'm in third grade math, trying to learn all this, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Express $R$ in the area formula $A=2\pi hR$ in term of $h$ and $r$, which comes out as
$$R= \frac12h\left(1+\frac{r^2}{h^2}\right)$$